# Regex expression for filtering based on multiple values

Tags: regex

I want a Regex expression that allows me to define multiple values that should be matched exactly.

In this case let's say that I want to match the exact value I put in (not case sensitive) which is: Audiobook & Audio book.If the data I have is the one below, my output should be 2 matched (since Audiobooks have an additional s). I have tried

```
(?:^|\W)audiobook(?:$|\W)|(?:^|\W)*?Audio book(?:$|\W)
```

but it seems like it is not providing the correct data since I only get one of the values returned.

Audiobooks

audiobook

E-book

Book

book

Listen to book
Audio book

Comment: is it grep regex? perl? java? some library? in general you want `\b(audiobook|Audio book)\b`

Comment: What have you done to indicate that the match should be non-case-sensitive?

Comment: @YuryNevinitsin thanks for the reply. Appreciate the help Yury. So I am using Supermetrics which is an add-on for Google Sheets. In Supermetrics they have an option where I can fetch data, using the criterias "Matches Regex". I honestly don't know what type of Regex it is. In their support forum, one employee advises a person to use "/\bYOUR SEARCH QUERY\b/" for another problem. Can this piece help determine what type of language it is? Looking forward to the response.

Comment: @ScottHunter Hi Scott, so I've tried to find a complete code on Stackoverflow, I have not personally indicated for it to be case-sensitive. However, I would really appreciate help solving this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a word boundary `\b` to prevent the word being part of a longer word and use an optional part to match an optional space and an optional s after book.

To make the match case insensitive, you might set a flag at your tool or language.

```
\bAudio(?: ?books?)?\b
```

- `\bAudio` Word boundary and match `Audio` (or use `[aA]udio` without case insensitive flag)
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `?books?` Match a space, `book` and optional `s`
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo with case insensitive flag](https://regex101.com/r/X4Mw5J/1)